# Weka attribute selection output

Tags: attributes, selection, weka

I want to perform attribute selection in Weka, but my dataset is rather big, and the program runs quite a while. That's why I want to see the current best set of attributes found. How do I do it?
For example, genetic search has the "Report Frequency" parameter, but all the results are shown after the whole search is finished, that's not what I need.

There is no progress bar, so I don't even know for how long will I have to wait...

Comment: What specifically are you trying to do? Feature ranking?

Comment: No, I just want to select features.
Though it can easily be done after ranking, but it wasn't my aim.

Answer (score 1):

Feature or Attribute selection is a standard problem in data-mining and Machine learning domains.

If you want to select a good set of attributes, you must **preprocess** your data by ranking attributes based on their quality. **Ranking Methods** such as **p-metric** or **t-statistic** are popular, which are based on statistical measures. One cannot simply go about by randomly selecting attributes from a large set without any sort of intuition on the nature of attributes.

Comment: Of course, I understand this. I had preprocessed my data (by standartization) and run the Weka implementation of the genetic algorithm, my question was about it. Didn't get your point...

Comment: @abhinna11 Can you please take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71119712/attribute-selection-in-weka-work-gave-weird-result

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need to run the attribute selection on your whole dataset you could use a smaller sample of your dataset (simply edit your ARFF file) to run the attribute selection.

Comment: Well, I think it will be better to use the whole dataset, because the result can change.
But even if I will reduce my data set (by the way, it's easier to do it in Weka), it won't be enough to make it 2 times smaller… So it's a big loss =\

Comment: So if you think that you need to run it on the whole dataset anyway why do you care about seeing intermediate results? Just let it run to completion. But maybe results do not change after a certain amount of data has been processed. You could try that by performing the algorithm on increasing dataset sizes until there is no change in attribute selection when the dataset size is increased.

Comment: I wanted at least to see how much time it will take, f.ex. in progress bar.
Because otherwise it's impossible to know, is it a day or a week…

Comment: Also it will be nice to see current results so I can run in parallel my algorithm with these features and see if it significantly improves quality